# Using CSS ch unit at size

Tags: html, css

How can I have `ch` calculation at specific font size?

For example, I want two `input`s with width `30ch@18px`, but displayed font with non-`18px` font size. See example below. Both `input`s should have the same width.

I tried setting `font-size: 18px` before `ch`, and setting `font-size` to other size after `ch`, but order doesn't matter.

```css
input {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#a {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 30ch;
}

#b {
  /* use 18px for ch calculation, but 10px for actual font size*/
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 30ch;

  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="text" placeholder="30ch at 18px font size"><br/>
<input id="b" type="text" placeholder="30ch at 10px font size">
```

Comment: Could you describe why it is you need this, as opposed to having input width say in px units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculated/rendered width specified in `ch` units is always relative to the current font-size.

A workaround might be to wrap both inputs in a parent `<div>` with a width of 30ch. Both inputs can just inherit this wrapper's width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-wrp {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 30ch;
  height: 4em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inp {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.inp-a {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.inp-b {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrp">
  <input class="inp inp-a" id="a" type="text" placeholder="30ch at 18px font size">
  <input class="inp inp-b" id="b" type="text" placeholder="30ch at 10px font size">
</div>
```

Display `flex` could be used to get same input heights.

Comment: Is there a way so that the _height_ of the `10px` `input` is the same as if `ch@18px` is used too?

Comment: See updated example. Essentially you need to specify a height for the parent element. See also [css-trick complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)